# how to make this text array change color when it is called a bone when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDchQ.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB3xj.jpg)----------

```js
//Escriba el código JQuery, señalando el número de caso
$(document).ready(function(){
//caso 01
$("#banner").css({"width":"100%","height":"400px"}); 
//caso 02
$("#marco section").css("width","100%");
//caso 03
$("section article").css({"width":"100%","text-align":"center","float":"left","margin-bot":"10px"});
//caso 04
$("section article img").css({"width":"80px","height":"50px","cursor":"pointer","border":"3px outset red"});
//caso 05
$("section article").find("label").css({"color":"blue","font-size":"10pt","font-weight":"bold"});
//caso 06
$("section article").find("input").css({"border":"3px double skyblue","font-size":"10pt","font-weight":"bold"});
//caso 07
var imagen = $("section article img"); 
imagen.mouseover(function(){
   $(this).fadeTo(1000,0.6).css({"border-radius":"10px","border":"3px solid gold"});
  });
//caso 08
imagen.mouseout(function(){
   $(this).fadeTo(1000,1).css({"border-radius":"0px","border":"3px outset red"});
  });
//caso 09

var arrlugares = ["Macchu-Picchu(Cuzco-Perú)","Coliseo(Roma-Italia)",
      "Chichen-Itza(Yucatán-México)","Cristo Redentor(Río de Janeiro-Brasil)","Taj-Mahal(Uttar Pradesh-India)","Muralla-China(Huairo-China)","Petra(Jordania)"];
    
var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);

   
 //calling  array and make  change  the img  when its  click
imagen.each(function(x,imagenes){
   $(imagenes).click(function(){
    $("header h2").text(arrlugares[x]);
    $("header h2").css("color",colores[n]);
    $("#banner").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
   }); 
 });
    
$(function(){ 
  var colors = ['#ff6','#6ff','#f6f','#f66','#66f','#6f6']; 
  $('input').click(function(){ 
      var randomcolor=Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
      //alert(randomcolor); 
      $('section').css('color',colors[randomcolor]); 
  }); 
});
```

```css
body { background:#76A5CC; font-family: arial; }

#marco { width:80%; height:auto; float:left;
      margin-left:10%; background-color:white; border: 2px solid white;
    }

#banner { width:80px; height:20px; float:left; }

header, nav { width:100%; height:auto; float:left; margin-bottom:5px; }

aside { width:30%; height:auto; float:left; }

section { width:70%; height:auto; float:left; }

nav { text-align:center; background-color:#76A5CC; }

footer { width:100%; height:auto; float:left; background-color:#76A5CC; text-align:center; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; }

header>h2 { text-align:center; color:#FFF; }

section>article h2 { color:#76A5CC; }

a:link {
 color: blue;
}
.redsocial { width:10px; height:10px; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Características JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo.css" />
  <script language="javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="../js/principe.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="marco">
   <header>
    <img src="../img/banner.jpg" id="banner" />
    <h2>Las maravillas del mundo</h2>
   </header>
     
   <section>
       //those are imgs
    
    <article>
     <a href="#portfolio"><img src="../img/maravillas/macchu-picchu.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/coliseo.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/chichen-itza.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/cristo-redentor.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/taj-mahal.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/muralla-china.jpg" />
     <img src="../img/maravillas/petra.jpg" />
    </article>
    
    <article>
     <h2>Datos del contacto</h2>
     <form>
      <label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" /><br/>
      <label>Apellido:</label><input type="text" /><br/>
      <label>Dirección:</label><input type="text" />
     </form>
    </article>
   </section>
   
   <footer>
    <p>Redes sociales</p>
    <img src="../img/social/fb1.png" class="redsocial" />
    <img src="../img/social/gp1.png" class="redsocial" />
    <img src="../img/social/tw1.png" class="redsocial" />
    <img src="../img/social/yt1.png" class="redsocial" />
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5bnI.png)

By clicking on each image (img) within the section article block, perform:
to. Show the description of the image in h2 of the header block.
second. Apply a font color randomly.
do. Get the path of the image and assign it to the banner.

var arrlugares = ["Macchu-Picchu(Cuzco-Perú)","Coliseo(Roma-Italia)",
                  "Chichen-Itza(Yucatán-México)","Cristo Redentor(Río de Janeiro-Brasil)","Taj-Mahal(Uttar Pradesh-India)","Muralla-China(Huairo-China)","Petra(Jordania)"];

Comment: random color pls

Comment: Paste your code in the question not as an image. Also state what problem you are having.

Comment: please explain whats the issue is?

Comment: I already put everything

Comment: When you click on each image (img) inside the section section block, do:
a. Show the description of the image in h2 of the header block.
b. Apply a font color randomly.
c. Get the path of the image and assign it to the banner.

Comment: What do you mean "description of the image"? Apply a font color to what randomly?

Comment: I put 2 images at the beginning, when I click on those images a text comes out; I wish that when that text comes out the color will be different when I click it; random if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 29 in your code produces a floating point number. Arrays do not accept floating point numbers. Cast it to an integer. Use something like `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil`.

Actually I see you doing it in a few places in your code.

Try using your debugger to trace your code. What what it is doing.

I'm still not sure what you're asking but here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rpxZbPkaipImyd5qBxuW?p=preview) of clicking an image and changing color, from your code.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var colors = ['#ff6', '#6ff', '#f6f', '#f66', '#66f', '#6f6'];
      var arrlugares = ["Macchu-Picchu(Cuzco-Perú)", "Coliseo(Roma-Italia)", "Chichen-Itza(Yucatán-México)", "Cristo Redentor(Río de Janeiro-Brasil)", "Taj-Mahal(Uttar Pradesh-India)", "Muralla-China(Huairo-China)", "Petra(Jordania)"];

      $('img').click(function(evnt) {
        var randomcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length),
          randomText = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrlugares.length);

        $('#marco header h2')
          .css('color', colors[randomcolor])
          .text(arrlugares[randomText]);

        $('#banner').attr('src', $(evnt.currentTarget).attr('src'));
      });
    })
```

Comment: I'm making a banner and that banner changes the images when I click on the images below BUT the banner at the bottom has text that is mentioned in the images, everything is just the color of that text that is called when I click on the image change color for a random one is just text that I put there

Comment: pls  i change  all  help me pls

Comment: When you click on each image (img) inside the section section block, do:
a. Show the description of the image in h2 of the header block.
b. Apply a font color randomly.
c. Get the path of the image and assign it to the banner.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of changing the color of text after clicking an image.

Comment: Did this answer your question?